# Do the Cutkosky rules imply (perturbative) unitarity?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, unitarity

In most standard textbooks on relativistic QFT, the Cutksoky rules are presented as a consequence of unitarity of the S-Matrix. However, at least for scalar field theories, it appears that the Cutkosky rules are satisfied so long as the propagator is an analytic function of energy with the appropriate conditions on the imaginary contributions to $E$ from multiparticle states.

*My question is*: do the Cutkosky rules automatically imply (perturbative) unitarity, so long as the coupling constants obey the proper unitarity bounds? My question does not assume Lorentz invariance, but I am interested in understanding this question for both Lorentz violating and Lorentz invariant field theories.

*My Guess*: it seems like the Cutkosky rules are a consequence of unitarity, but the converse may fail. I think that is may be possible for the sum rule for the exact propagator for bare fields to be violated without predicting that any unphysical states are generated from cutting loop diagrams. Obviously, perturbative unitarity breaks down whenever the couplings exceed perturbative unitarity bounds. *Non-perturbatively*, I think there could exist a situation in which a particle's field strength renormalization is too large such that the contribution of the multiparticle spectrum in the exact propagator violates the sum rule.

Thoughts?

Comment: I don't think Cutkosky's rule contains sufficient dynamical information to conclude perturbative unitarity of, *e.g.* gauge-fixed Yang-Mills theory.  Cutkosky's rule is just a method to obtain the discontinuity of an analytic function across its cut.  Usually, the logic flows the other way: unitarity implies the analyticity.